# how can i increment the counter variable with another variable(function argument) in loop

Tags: javascript

> This throws all kinds of weird errors to me.

```
function range(start, end, addend) {
    var array = [];
    for (i = start; i <= end; i + addend)
        array.push(i)
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `return` should not be placed between quotes.

Comment: `return` should not have quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `return` hasn't to be a `string`.
- Use `i += addend` instead of `i + addend`, because `i + addend` will return `NaN` (causing `for` loop infinite).

```js
function range(start, end, addend) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i += addend) {
    array.push(i)
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(range(4, 20, 4));
```

Comment: please also add a `var` in front if the `i` so this var gets local and doesn't pollute the global namespace

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I've just realized it (: